# Unsigned APK with Android Studio 1.5.1

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Where does the Android Studio 1.5.1 keeps the unsigned APK? I have checked the "app\build\outputs\apk" location but there are only the signed with debug or release and unaligned. Unsigned doesn`t exist at all.

Since it is signed, it MUST exist the unsigned APK too. Where is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Android Gradle plugin won't expose an unsigned version of your APK if you have a signingConfig assigned to your buildType.  The moment you take out your signingConfig and rebuild (or build a debug version), you'll see something like this:

```
$ ./gradlew clean assembleRelease
$ find . -name \*.apk
./app/build/outputs/apk/app-<flavor>-release-unsigned.apk
```

Comment: Yes! that`s it :)) Thank you! I just needed to remove the signing configuration I have wrote in gradle.

Answer (score 8):

### **Generating the release unsigned build .apk**

you can create the unsigned apk with the gradle easily

1. Click on the drop down menu on the toolbar at the top (usually with android icon and name of your application)

   (If it is hard to find the Edit configuration option Search it with
   the search box in the right top of the window)
2. Select **Edit configurations**
3. Click **plus sign** at top left corner or press alt+insert
4. Select **Gradle**
5. Choose **your module** as Gradle project
6. In Tasks: enter `assemble`
7. Press OK
8. Press play

After that you should find your unsigned 'apk' in directory `ProjectName\app\build\outputs\apk`

Comment: As far as I can undestand, this does the same this as I would build from command line with gradle command "assembleRelease". This only builds the release and debug builds at the same time. I still can`t find unsigned apk at the ProjectName\app\build\outputs\apk location. I have noticed that the main diference between singer and unsigned APK is that the signed one contains META-INF dir inside. If I remove it, it acts as unsigned. Can I do that to obtain my unsigned apk-s ?

Comment: @AdrianIvasku i think you have missed something in above steps. Surely you will get `app-release-unsigned.apk` 

I have attached some screenshots
 1. Before following the above steps (only debug.apk file available in `ProjectName\app\build\outputs\apk`) [http://i.imgur.com/lwpVOwo.png]

2. Editing the Configurations Link (http://i.imgur.com/WWf2qFt.png)

3. After run the application again `app-release-unsigned.apk`  can be found in `ProjectName\app\build\outputs\apk` [http://i.imgur.com/piWz8aJ.png]

Comment: Thank you for the screenshoots but I followed those exact steps... it still donesn t give me unsigned apk. Maybe because I am using gradle experimental plugin 0.4.0.... I am puzzled.